# Android, java rx, asynchronous

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I have a screen that shows a list of items.

- First I want to show the elements from the local database.
- After the  user is viewing the local elements, check the internet and
  update  them (if the device has internet).

I have the following code fragments

```
Observable<Data> fetchFromdisk = ...;  
Observable<Data> fetchFromNetwork = ...;

Observable<Data>  fetchData= Observable.concat (fetchFromdisk ,fetchFromNetwork);
```

Then I'm doing the following

```
mSubscriptions.clear();
Subscription subscription = fetchData
        .subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.computation())
        .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.ui())
        .subscribe(
                new Subscriber<List<Data>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        view.setLoadingIndicator(false);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        processError(e);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<Data> data) {
                        processData(data);
                    }
                }

        );
mSubscriptions.add(subscription);
```

But what is happening is that fetchFromdisk is first run, then FetchFromNetwork is executed. Once emitting elements ends the execution of ProcessData begins.

That is quite the opposite of what I want to achieve.
I want to prioritize the user to see the data quickly and then go to the internet.
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Side point, You should be using `Schedulers.io()`

Comment: @Sourabh I already tried, but it did not work either

Comment: No, side point, I am not saying its a solution to your problem, but you should be using io anyway

Comment: @Sourabh Google uses computation () in its architecture examples https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp-rxjava/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/tasks/TasksPresenter.java

Comment: "Once emitting elements ends the execution of ProcessData begins." - are you sure about that? Have you tried to log it?

Comment: @MaximOstrovidov I think you are right. I have to edit the question. When the device has internet executes the observavles immeditaley. But when I desconnect the internet it takes time to start excecuiting the observables

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method .doOnCompleted to execute your code once the cache has been extracted.

```
mSubscriptions.clear();
Subscription subscription = fetchData
    .subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.computation())
    .doOnCompleted( new Action0<List<Notification>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(List<Data> cachedData) {
                      // Get data from server here.

                      // Compare new data against cached data. 

                      // Update cache.

                      // Process new data.
                }
            })
    .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.ui())
    .subscribe(
            new Subscriber<List<Data>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    view.setLoadingIndicator(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    processError(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Data> data) {
                    processData(data);
                }
            }

    );
    mSubscriptions.add(subscription);
```

///////// Non Solution Tip ////////

Try using a Single instead of an Observable, it can get rid of the onCompleted.
https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/issues/139

Answer (score 0):

It might be because your subscriber returns a List rather than Data?

Are you sure you are using the right observer? The concat operator should return a Observer with the same element.

```
    Observable<String> a = Observable.just("a");
    Observable<String> b = Observable.just("b");

    Observable<String> ab = Observable.concat(a,b);

    ab.subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String s) {
            Log.d("onNext", s);
        }
    });
```